# Actionscript 3 3d with fieldofview

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, perspective, fieldofview

what does the field of view to do with the z axis in flash? I have tried moving object towards the eye with different fieldofview values with same z axis but their size changes.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing either the z-axis *or* the [field of view](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html) will change the apparent size of your object:

Changing z-axis (ie **focalLength**) moves the object nearer/further to your eye, so it appears larger/smaller.

Changing **fieldOfView** changes the arc of your vision (kind of like using a fisheye or telephoto lens): if your field of view is large, your object will only take up a small part of that arc, so will appear small (=fisheye lens), but if your field of view is small (=telephoto) then your object occupies a large part of your arc, and appears big.

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [webfactional.com](http://roi.webfactional.com/img/so/fieldOfView.gif))</sub>

(In the diagrams, the dotted box is your stage area.)

Hope that helps explain things a bit.